# mysql4 missing auto_increment ids

Tags: mysql, auto-increment

We have a system which gets 1000's of queries a second and has several 1000 notes added a day. The note table is over 2.5 million records. We never delete a note and I have just found there are 19 missing id's in the id incremented field for that table for just today.

Any thoughts?

We are using mysql4 and are working on going to 5.
We are also running on windows 2003

Comment: This isn't really an answer, but -- the actual value of the number in an auto-increment field shouldn't be thought of as something meaningful. If you are ever doing something like "adding 1" to an auto-incremented field, you are assigning too much meaning to the number. With this point of view, my answer would be "You never should be in a position to notice that any id's are missing."

Comment: We have had some complaints that notes have been added but later are disappearing. We do not delete notes so we need a way to disproof the system might be loosing them or was it a user error.

Comment: Short of table corruption, there is no way that row would disappear from MySQL table - other than explicit `DELETE` query. And if your table were getting corrupted, you would know about that. Are you on MyISAM or on InnoDB BTW?

Comment: Innodb is the type. The missing id chucks are between just a few to 30 or so. I have seen a few chucks in the 1000's.

Answer (score 2):

This might be INSERT queries that failed for various reasons, or that were rolled back within transactions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't guarantee that the IDs are sequential. Normally what happens is that the transaction was rolled back. This can happen for lots of reasons - for instance, deadlock. The IDs are allocated before the rows get inserted, so if the insert creates a deadlock, and the thread loses, then the transaction is rolled back, the insert fails, and an ID gets "wasted".

This is not an abnormal situation; every application needs to be able to tolerate (some) deadlocks. This is part of using an engine such as InnoDB (and happens equally on MSSQL, Oracle etc).

Comment: Does that mean the data held while deadlock is lost? Or does it mean it just loads in later with a higher up ID? Is there a way to record when deadlocks happen and what is happening?

Comment: It returns an error to the application. It is the application's responsibility to retry in this case. You will get an appropriate error code and can handle it by your normal error handling procedure. If you did not retry, maybe you logged the error?